# Dynamic contacenation of cell values in dynamic range of columns in 4 different rows

Tags: excel, vba

Goal: I want to build 4 different strings with method Contagenation. I have a dynamic count of columns (column 4 to maxCol) in each of 4 rows (row 32 to row 35) in sheet ("Calc"). The 4 different strings should be stored in another sheet ("CreateColumns")in cells (A1, A2, A3, A4)

Problem: I have coded the following code to achieve that goal but in sheet ("CreateColumns") each of the 4 rows are filled with the same value = last value of row 35 in sheet("Calc") and not with the 4 different values as intended.

Question: What is the error in my code?

```
Sub CreateColumns()
Dim maxCol As Integer
Dim x As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim row As Long
Dim y As Long
    Sheets("Calc").Select
    maxCol = Cells(32, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
      For row = 32 To 35
      Sheets("Calc").Select
      Cells(row, 4).Activate
         For i = 4 To maxCol
            With Worksheets("Calc")
                Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 4), .Cells(row, maxCol))
            End With            
         x = ""
            For Each cel In rng
                x = x & cel.Value
                  For y = 1 To 4
                    Sheets("ColCreate").Cells(y, 1).Value = x
                  Next
             Next
         Next
      Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is that the part where you paste to sheet "ColCreate" is a bit out of place - it should occur once for each occurence of your outermost loop, alongside the "y" increment

I have slightly amended your code below, should provide the expected result

```
Sub CreateColumns()
    Dim maxCol As Integer
    Dim x As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim row As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Sheets("Calc").Select
    maxCol = Cells(32, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    y = 1
    For row = 32 To 35
       Sheets("Calc").Select
       Cells(row, 4).Activate
       For i = 4 To maxCol
          With Worksheets("Calc")
              Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 4), .Cells(row, maxCol))
          End With
          x = ""
          For Each cel In rng
              x = x & cel.Value
          Next
       Next
    Sheets("ColCreate").Cells(y, 1).Value = x
    y = y + 1
    Next
End Sub
```